# Stl List Iterator Error

Tags: c++, stl

I have to implement my own list with the stl for my data structures class here is the code I have.

Playlist.h

```
#ifndef PLAYLIST_H
#define PLAYLIST_H

#include <iostream>
using std::ostream;

#include <list>
using std::list;

class Song;

class Playlist
{
public:
    void append(const char* name, const char* artist);
    list<Song>::iterator find(const char* name) const;
    void delete_song(const char* name);
    void print(ostream& out) const;

private:
    list<Song> plist;
};

ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Playlist& playlist);

#endif  /* PLAYLIST_H */


ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Playlist& playlist);

#endif  /* PLAYLIST_H */
```

Playlist.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using std::ostream;
using std::endl;

#include <cstring>

#include "Song.h"
#include "Playlist.h"

void Playlist::append(const char* name, const char* artist)
{
    Song song(name, artist);
    plist.push_back(song);
}

list<Song>::iterator Playlist::find(const char* name) const
{
    list<Song>::iterator itr = plist.begin(); // error occurs here
    while(itr != plist.end() && strcmp(itr->get_name(), name) == 0)
    {
        itr++;
    } 

    return itr;
}

void Playlist::delete_song(const char* name)
{
    list<Song>::iterator itr = find(name);
    if (itr != plist.end())
        plist.erase(itr);
}

void Playlist::print(ostream& out) const
{
    list<Song>::iterator itr = plist.begin(); // error occurs here
    while (itr != plist.end())
    {
       out << *itr << endl;
       itr++;
    }
} 

ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Playlist& playlist)
{
    playlist.print(out);
    return out;
}
```

When I try to compile this I get:

error: conversion from ‘std::list::const_iterator {aka std::_List_const_iterator}’ to non-scalar type ‘std::list::iterator {aka std::_List_iterator}’ requested

in both places marked in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `void Playlist::print(ostream& out) const` is designated const. Thus plist is `const` and so `plist.begin()` returns a `const_iterator`. You will either have to remove the const from the method, use const_cast(worst solution), or simply use a const_iterator to iterate over the list(best option).

Answer (score 1):

Use `list<Song>::const_iterator itr = plist.begin();`

You are declaring the method as `const` which marks the object on which it is being executed as const. So you should not be allowed to change the members. But regular `iterator` allows changing the object it references. For this purpose, `const_iterator` was created - it works similarly, but you do not have ability to change the object it is pointing to.

**EDIT 2**
You could remove `const` from the method and it would compile, but it is a bad idea - your method is lookup, it does not alter the object contents, and so the interface should indicate that explicitly.

Comment: use a little more detail please? I'd like to know why

Answer (score 1):

Your method is marked const (i.e it doesn't have the right to modify the instance variables), but you access to your list with an iterator which is not marked const ;and by returning it for instance you could modify the instance variable and break the "const" keyword of the method.

Hope that Im clear

Answer (score 0):

if you're in a const method, you can only call the begin method returning a const_iterator, so you should use those instead of simple iterators.

Answer (score 0):

In both places, you are invoking the const version of `List::begin()`, which return `List::const_iterator`.

```
list<Song>::const_iterator itr = plist.begin();
```

should fix the problem, but then you need the signature of your methods to return const_iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is what the error message says it is.

It was you who declared `Playlist::print` as a `const` method of the class. This immediately means that inside that method all class members now have `const` types. Your `plist` will have type `const list<Song>` inside `Playlist::print`. Methods `begin()`/`end()` of const containers return `const_iterator` for those containers. You cannot initialize/assign `iterator` with an `const_iterator`. That's what the compiler is telling you.

Either switch to `const_iterator` inside those methods, or stop declaring these methods `const`.

In case of `Playlist::print` the answer is obvious: just switch to `const_iterator`.

In case of `Playlist::find` it might be a different story. It is a matter of your intent. If you just switch to `const_iterator` inside `Playlist::find`, you will have to return `const_iterator` from it. Does that work for you? But if you want to be able to modify the playlist from outside through the returned iterator, you will typically have to implement two versions of `Playlist::find`: a const one, returning `const_iterator`, and a non-const one, returning `iterator`.